# Set data retention for application-insights using Azure CLI

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-cli

Is it possible to set data retention for application-insights using Azure CLI (az)?

Preferably during resource creation with `az monitor app-insights component create`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use this cli command: [az resource update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/resource?view=azure-cli-latest#az-resource-update).

The example code:

```
az resource update --resource-group your_resource_group --name appInsights_name --resource-type "microsoft.insights/components" --set properties.RetentionInDays=180
```

Test result(you may need to **refresh the web page** so you can see the new retention value in azure portal.):

[image]

**Note:** The valid value for RetentionInDays should be one of these: `30, 60, 90, 120, 180, 270, 365, 550 or 730`. The reference doc is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/data-retention-privacy#how-long-is-the-data-kept).

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer. But according to this page : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/data-retention-archive?tabs=portal-1%2Cportal-2 , we can set the interactive retention between 4 and 730 days. I am wondering where I can set the retention to for example 7 days. it would be great if you could help me out.